# Check if array of objects contains multiple values from another array of objects and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects `list.data` that contains about 2000 objects. I have other array `docs` that has one object that already exists in the `list.data` array. I would like to find duplicate/duplicates and remove them from the `docs` array. The object is a duplicate if it has same values saved in three properties (name, quizmaster, file). Otherwise it is not duplicate.
So far I have tried this code:

```
const filtered = docs.filter(doc => list.data.some(el => doc.name !== el.name && doc.quizmaster !== el.quizmaster && doc.file !== el.file));
```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects) fix your problem?

Comment: @Toasty No, I want to find the duplicates based on two arrays, not find duplicates in one array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions should be the other way around:

```
docs.filter(doc => !list.data.some(el =>
    doc.name === el.name 
    && doc.quizmaster === el.quizmaster 
    && doc.file === el.file));
```

or

```
docs.filter(doc => list.data.every(el =>
    doc.name !== el.name 
    || doc.quizmaster !== el.quizmaster 
    || doc.file !== el.file));
```

If you're doing this multiple times in a hot loop, consider creating a compound key from these properties (e.g. `el.name + '/' + el.quizmaster...`) and maintain a `Set` of keys, in which case you can get rid of the inner filter.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
array1 = array1.filter(function(val) {
  return array2.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```

or if you like it shorter:

```
array1 = array1.filter(val => !array2.includes(val));
```

---

### References

- [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)